# Fetch data from a table

Tags: r, cassandra, nosql

I tried to connect to Cassandra DB from R to fetch data from a table.

I referred to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCassandra/RCassandra.pdf as well.

Alternate option is to use rJava library in R and load Cassandra drivers in R to connect to Cassandra DB. But driver has limitation in dataframe size that it receives. Hence wanted to use RCassandra.

```
    library(RCassandra)
    conn <- RC.connect(host="xx.xx.xx.xx", port=9160)
    conn <- RC.login(conn, username = "abc", password = "def")
    a<-RC.cluster.name(conn)
    b<-RC.use(conn, "keyspacename")
    RC.read.table(conn, "tablename")
    RC.get.range.slices(conn, "table1", limit=10)
```

**output error for 6th line**:

> > Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> >     check.names = TRUE,  :    duplicate row.names:

**output for last line (7th line)

> ** key value           ts 1            1.507174e+15 2            1.507174e+15 3            1.507174e+15 4            1.507174e+15 5            1.507174e+15 6            1.507174e+15 7            1.507174e+15 8            1.507174e+15 9            1.507174e+15 10           1.507174e+15
>
> [[84]]    key                  value           ts 1
>   1.507711e+15 2             \fp 1.507711e+15 3                             1.507711e+15 4             \fr 1.507711e+15